# Are GPUs good for case-based image filtering?

Tags: image-processing, cuda, gpu

I am trying to figure out whether a certain problem is a good candidate for using CUDA to put the problem on a GPU.

I am essentially doing a box filter that changes based on some edge detection. So there are basically 8 cases that are tested for for each pixel, and then the rest of the operations happen - typical mean calculations and such. Is the presence of these switch statements in my loop going to cause this problem to be a bad candidate to go to GPU?

I am not sure really how to avoid the switch statements, because this edge detection has to happen at every pixel. I suppose the entire image could have the edge detection part split out from the processing algorithm, and you could store a buffer corresponding to which filter to use for each pixel, but that seems like it would add a lot of pre-processing to the algorithm.

Edit: Just to give some context - this algorithm is already written, and OpenMP has been used to pretty good effect at speeding it up. However, the 8 cores on my development box pales in comparison to the 512 in the GPU.

Comment: if by "pales" you mean in raw numbers, this is not necessarily true, as many of the commentators in this thread have explained that programming for the GPU requires a different type of thinking. this is because, even though it is a workhorse, it is only fit for certain tasks. :)

Comment: if you have access to a Fermi-based card from nVidia, give it a go and port the part of the code where you have hotspots. you might also want to look into profiling your code if you have not done so already, to see what the actual bottleneck is. otherwise your best bet is to re-write it so that it does not branch.

Answer (score 1):

Edge detection, mean calculations and cross-correlation can be implemented as 2D convolutions. Convolutions can be implemented on GPU very effectively ([speed-up > 10, up to 100](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20220) with respect to CPU), especially for large kernels. So yes, it may make sense rewriting image filtering on GPU.

Though I wouldn't use GPU as a development platform for such a method.

Comment: i added soem context - we already have this running, and parallelized somewhat with OpenMP

Answer (score 1):

typically, unless you are on the new CUDA architecture, you will want to avoid branching. because GPUs are basically SIMD machines, the pipleline is extremely vurnurable to, and suffers tremendously from, pipeline stalls due to branch misprediction.

if you think that there are significant benefits to be garnered by using a GPU, do some preliminary benchmarks to get a rough idea.

if you want to learn a bit about how to write non-branching code, head over to http://cellperformance.beyond3d.com/ and have a look.

further, investigating into running this problem on multiple CPU cores might also be worth it, in which case you will probably want to look into either OpenCL or the Intel performance libraries (such as TBB)

another go-to source for problems targeting the GPU be it graphics, computational geometry or otherwise, is IDAV, the Institute for Data Analysis and Visualization: http://idav.ucdavis.edu

Answer (score 1):

Branching is actually not that bad, if there is spatial coherence in the branching.  In other words, if you are expecting chunks of pixels next to each other in the image to go through the same branch, the performance hit is minimized.

Comment: this is true for newer Nvidia processors; not sure about AMD/ATi?

Comment: also, given that the problem is edge detection, diverging execution paths would obviously happen around the edges, although this performance hit may be insignificant depending on the image geometry

Answer (score 0):

Using a GPU for processing can often be counter-intuitive; things that are obviously inefficient if done in normal serial code, are actually the best way to do it in parallel using the GPU.

The pseudo-code below looks inefficient (since it computes 8 filtered values for every pixel) but will run efficiently on a GPU:

---

```
# Compute the 8 possible filtered values for each pixel
for i = 1...8
    # filter[i] is the box filter that you want to apply
    # to pixels of the i'th edge-type
    result[i] = GPU_RunBoxFilter(filter[i], Image)

# Compute the edge type of each pixel
# This is the value you would normally use to 'switch' with
edge_type = GPU_ComputeEdgeType(Image)

# Setup an empty result image
final_result = zeros(sizeof(Image))
# For each possible switch value, replace all pixels of that edge-type
# with its corresponding filtered value
for i = 1..8
    final_result = GPU_ReplacePixelIfTrue(final_result, result[i], edge_type==i)
```

---

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: am i reading this right - that you are saying to basically calculate all of those filters ahead of time for the whole image, same with the edge type?

Comment: yes. It seems wasteful of computation, since normally you would only have to calculate one "filtered value" per pixel and here you would compute 8 values, but it avoids branching.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, control flow usually has performance penalty on GPU, be it *if's / switch'es / ternary operator's*, because with control flow operations GPU can't optimally run threads. So usual tactics is to avoid branching as possible. In some cases IF's can be replaced by some formula, where IF conditions maps to formula coefficients. But concrete solution/optimization depends on concrete GPU kernel... Maybe you can show exact code, to be analyzed further by stackoverflow community.

**EDIT:**
Just in case you are interested here is [convolution pixel shader](http://coding-experiments.blogspot.com/2010/07/convolution.html) that i wrote.

Comment: I will look into that - showing code. It may be too proprietary at this point to release